# What is the best tool to perform an automated/unattended virtual guest os install?

Tags: linux, installation, unix, virtual-machine, automation

I would like to be able to add (and remove) virtual machines from my Ubuntu (12.04) host OS using 'unattended guest os installation' method.

What I mean here is to pass a command to the software via the terminal like :

`create_vm --name virtual_name --type Linux_Ubuntu --iso_file ubuntu12.04.iso ......`

What is the best tool to do this ? Is it possible to be done with VirtualBox software ?